# How can I, using current web tech, generate a hexagonal, interactive map

Tags: javascript, html, dictionary, hexagonal-tiles

I want to learn html5/current web techs, specifically to create a game.

Initially I want to be able to generate a top down, 2d map, made up of hexagonal tiles.

These tiles will be randomly generated with the usual environmental tiles (grass, plains, snow, lake, ocean etc...)

I want to be able to zoom in/out.

I will later want to have avatars represent the player(s)/AIs and assets on the tiles etc...

Where can I find a good starting place to learn the basics?

Comment: I think your options are any of: Flash, HTML5 Canvas or SVG. However I wonder if this question is a bit too discursive for S/O, hence the downvotes!

Answer (score 4):

Check out this blog post http://build-failed.blogspot.com/2012/04/maps-and-boardgames-part-3-client-side.html. The author has done a 2D hexagonal tile map with zoom in and zoom out. You can study the code to get you started. You will have to add the avatars and a different map.

There's no one place to learn the basics, but this other blog is a good place to start on game programming: http://www-cs-students.stanford.edu/~amitp/gameprog.html#hex

Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

For the start i recomand you to use the canvas tag of HTML5 and a framework like http://calebevans.me/projects/jcanvas/index.php. You will find good documentations and examples on the net. Is very easy to learn but more code.

If you want less code and better results try a JS game engine from here : http://ntt.cc/2011/01/31/66-open-source-javascript-game-engine-for-serious-developers.html.